# Как Отсортировать Dictionary по ключу состоящий из кортежа, и отсортировать по второму элементу кортежа C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

В общем, у меня есть такой код:

```
 Dictionary<(int, int), int> _data = new Dictionary<(int, int), int>();
```

как его отсортировать по ключу, а точнее по второму элемента этого ключа

Comment: `var sorted = _data.OrderBy(x => x.Key.Item2);`...

Comment: а не используя LINQ&)